# span with double f, strange performance in chrome

Tags: html, css

Why is the highlight on "ort" instead of "fort"?
This seems to be the case when there are two `f`'s. When I replace `f` with other letters, such as d, it displays normally. So maybe this is a bug in chrome?

chrome version is chrome83.
add: It seems to be related to the font.

[image]

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.highlight-font {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>ef</span><span class="highlight-font">fort</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice catch. I think you are right. It might be some kind of Chromium bug. Firefox works well.

Comment: Google Chrome VS. 83.0.4103.116 -  Work.

Comment: Works fine in W10-x64 Chrome 83, Edge 83, IE11 and Firefox 79. Maybe do a [Ctrl-F5] and reload the page?

Comment: Maybe I got the answer, it can be controlled by font-variant-ligatures.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures

Comment: Yes, it's related to ligatures. In many fonts, sequential `f` characters combine into a single `ff` glyph for readability.

Comment: did you try to make the span inline-block elements? it should fix the issue too

Comment: What font is being used in your image?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's **Chromium based browsers bug** (I see same bug, Opera 69). It works well on Firefox etc.
You can use some invisible character if you need some **hotfix** right now.
I've used `&zwnj;` and it works well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    .highlight-font {
      color: green;
    }
  </style>

<body>
  <div>
    <span>ef</span>&zwnj;<span class="highlight-font">fort</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think its better to put the Zero-Width character inside one of the *span* and not outside them to not break the dom or possible css span + span rules

Comment: @iguypouf You are right. It makes sense. I meant to insert anything what is not visible helps .